# Best practice for responsive html anchors

Tags: html, css, svg, anchor, responsive

I use anchors for different sections in a svg on a website. While browsing the website with a 27" screen, scrolling to the sections are fine but if I switch to a 24" screen or a 17", you can cleary see a offset.

```
        <foreignObject x="5" y="-20" style="position: absolute">
            <a href="" id="section-1"></a>
        </foreignObject>
```

[image]

Should I have work with CSS + @media? Or do I need to calculate the value with JS based on the viewport?

What is the best practice for setting responsive "slide to" html anchors?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You don't need to put the `<a>` inside a foreign object. In SVG you have the `<a>` SVG element to create a hyperlink to other web pages. Please read about [The <a> SVG element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a)